# Regex For Extracting First 4 letters of search term

Tags: regex

I am using a redirection plugin and want to redirect the existing search url

`http://www.example.com/search/abcdef` to `http://www.example.com/?s=abcd`

I am able to redirect `/search/abcdef` to `/?s=abcdef` however I can't get hold of how to trim and use the first of characters of search term i.e `abcd` in short it should look like `/?s=abcd`

As of now I am using following regex with plugin:

Source URL - `/search/(.*)`

Target URL - `http://www.example.com/?s=$1`

I'd appreciate any pointers in that direction or maybe a working answer ;)

Comment: How are you redirecting? There are already close votes on this question for being off-topic and I am tempted to add one unless I see some valid WordPress components.

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear as to what I want. Here's the plugin I am using for handling redirection - http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ As already mentioned above, I have already modified the "/search/abcdef" part of url to match that of wordpress inbuilt search mechanism. What I am trying to accomplish here is to extract first 4 characters of "abcdef" and use it with "/?s=" parameter. I hope it makes some sense now.

Comment: Please don't comment, but add that as edit instead.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a Regex. There's [`substr( $string, int $offset );`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) built into PHP to achieve that.

Comment: True. But I am specifically looking out for a regex to achieve the same since the plugin I am using (Redirection) requires regex.

Comment: @Paritosh So [Google was no option](https://www.google.at/search?q=regex+first+four+characters&oq=regex+first+four&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.5425j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? ... `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$` for alphanumeric first four characters...

Comment: Yes, it was and is an option but I can't find a related topic. String matching results dominate my queries. Hence the thought of posting here :)

Comment: @Paritosh What I showed you in above comment (the working Regex), was extracted from the first search result in above linked Google search results page ;)

Comment: I am looking for a regex alternative not it's analogous function. I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: Then please update your question. Btw, I still don't understand your question.

Comment: Are you serious, @Paritosh ? You've now gotten an analogous function *as well as* a regex.